# ASP.NET MVC Automatic Logout and go back to Login Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application, and I am looking to implement a Logout on session/cookie expiration.

I have the Backend piece complete. If I don't do anything it times out after 10-15 minutes and when I click on another option it redirects me to the Login Page.

I have missing the client side. I have tried implementing a script that executes every 5 seconds, but now it never timesout. I have also implemented a Filter to try to solve it.

Here is the code in the backend:

```
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                { 
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),
                }
            });
```

I implemented a script on the client side (it never redirects the page):

```
        $(function () {
            setInterval(checkSession, 5000);
        });
        function checkSession() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/security/ayst",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (repJSON) {
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    if (xhr.status === 401) {
                        console.log("unauth");
                        window.location.href = xhr.Data.LogOnUrl;
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I have a controller action and filter also:

```
        [MyAuthorize]
        [Route("security/ayst")]
        public ActionResult Ayst()
        {
            string data = "Ok";
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Filter:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        Error = "NotAuthorized",
                        LogOnUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl
                    },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                // this is a standard request, let parent filter to handle it
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe the reason it e=never redirects is that it detects requests and therefore the expiration cookie is incremented.

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: You're using SlidingExpiration and keep sending requests... The session will never expire this way.

Comment: @Okta Yes, that's what I thought. ButI cant redirect the client to the login page from the backend. So, what would I need to do to check when the session expires to redirect to the login page?

Comment: When the backend gets a request which is not authenticated, it will redirect the client to the login page, you have already defined that with this line:

LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")

Also, I think your main problem here is time discrepancy between your client and the backend, they both expect 5 minutes, however, you need to read the documentation for SlidingExpiration.

Comment: @Okta Thanks for that. I will review the documentation. And while without the javascript code the solution works in the sense that when the user goes to an action it redirects them to login, I want to make sure the client is not displaying the data from the app. So I still need to figure a way to redirect the client to the login page, and I don't believe I can do that from the server.